# How to place a bathroom vent fan in a vaulted/cathedral ceiling?

Tags: bathroom, shower, vent, ventilation

I'm planning a renovation where the ceiling over the shower is vaulted to the rafters (see elevation below). Where is the optimal or recommended place to put a vent fan in this scenario? The rafters will be filled with closed cell foam.

The area on the top left side of the wall is attic space (where the current fan -pre-renovation- is already ducted). Is it reasonable to mount the fan in that, i.e. on its side? If I do, it seems like there will always be some small amount of space up to the peak that will be above the fan's intake - problem?

Is the best case just to build out a chase in the peak to flatten it out just enough to mount the fan unit in the expected horizontal configuration?

[image: Plan for shower ceiling]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to have a fan mounted in a vertical wall. Just attach it to the current ductwork (as long as it is vented to the outside).